# SQL Views - How to determine underlying tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have been gathering data from a view for reporting purposes quite some time related to volume, SLA, etc...

However I want to know what tables make up the view itself..I am currently using SQL Server 2012 and I have been asked some questions on the underlying data within the view...however we have hundreds of tables and I don't know where to look..

Just wondering if there is a quick way to check which tables make up a view..

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean looking at the view definition? e.g. Right-clicking the view and clicking "Design".

Comment: 1 minute search: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1638/using-sql-server-meta-data-to-list-tables-that-make-up-views/

Comment: Thanks a lot guys...my apologies..I was previously trying to google and not finding any results.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Right-click the view and click "Design" (as already mentioned)
2. Right-click the view. Select "Script View as" > "CREATE to" > "New Query Editor Window"
3. Right-click the view. Select "View Dependencies". Then select the "Objects on which  depends" radio button.

Hope that helps you out.

Marius